# Turborepo: transpilePackages for internal packages

Tags: typescript, next.js, turborepo

In the official documentation regarding internal packages, it states that you need to transpile them in the `next.config.js`: `transpilePackages: ['math-helpers']` ([sharing-code](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages)).

Also, in the current starter examples (`npx create-turbo@latest`), `@repo/ui` is transpiled in the next apps.

However, all next apps work even without transpiling internal packages.

Do you have to transpile internal packages in the `next.config`? If yes, why? Or is it not necessary? If not, why is it done in both the documentation and the examples?

Ideally, I would like to bundle internal packages in the regular build/dev step without transpiling them in advance.

I use npm as a package manager. I would expect, that internal packages are just resolved via symlinks and bundled into the apps.